# Check if field was set in proto3 (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I see answers to this question like using `IMessageExtensions.HasField(person, "name")` but I can't find them anymore.

I want to process the message from the sender that might be using older protocol version generated from older proto files and deduce if it is the case. I.e. if sender doesn't yet know about recently added field.

For example, this is an older version:

```
message Person {
    string name = 1;
    string surname = 2;
}
```

and this is a newer version:

```
message Person {
    string name = 1;
    string surname = 2;
    string middlename = 3;
}
```

I'd like to know if the sender was using older version and (probably) put middle name into `name` field or it's a message from newer version and I can expect data is correct.

Note: both sender and receiver are using proto3 version.

Comment: There is no payload difference between "didn't know about `middlename`" vs "knew about `middlename`, but didn't set a value"; would it perhaps be better to just check whether `middlename` *has a non-empty value*?

Comment: Seems I found possible solution here:
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/Reflection/IFieldAccessor.cs#L38 (comment).
For proto3 fields that aren't explicitly optional, this throws an InvalidOperationException. This means there is a concept of "explicitly optional fields", i.e. I can declare middlename as "optional string middlename = 3;" and the even explicit getter HasMiddlename will be generated. Need to play more with it, though.

Comment: Yes, using proto3 `optional` is precisely the approach to take here.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think I can get away with string fields because they may be null or empty strings. However for struct types (like int32) I don't have a way around.